# Add data from SQL Server Data base

Tags: node.js

How can I fetch The Data from sqlServer ?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I want to make a router for product and i don't know why

Comment: You don't know *why* you want to do something?!

Comment: Do you use [Express](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html)?

Comment: No , I'm beginner , beacause this reason I need help, To make it clear to me.@jonrsharpe

Comment: yes ,I use Express @ pzaenger
Thank you for your answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use express to expose a service for your products, which will communicate with your database where you can perform CRUD operations on your products table. For example

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');


var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "yourHost",
  user: "yourusername",
  password: "yourpassword",
  port:"yourPort"

});


app.get('/products', function (req, res) {
   con.connect(function(err) {
     if (err) throw err;
     con.query("SELECT * from records", function (err, result) {
       if (err) throw err;
       con.close();
       res.send(JSON.stringify(result))
    });
  });
})

app.listen(3000);
```

Put this code in your index.js file or main.js file of your node project.
After that open your terminal and use CURL to test your service.
curl -X POST "http://localhost:3000/products". Or you can simply type http://localhost:3000/products in your browser and it will give you all product records.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Hassan Tariq

Comment: Please upvote if it solves your problem. @MarioNelban7

Comment: I'm so sorry,I voted wrong, my problem was solved by you and I gave you a voice @Hassan Tariq